# Type classes and levity polymorphism

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a class for values that can be unboxed/reboxed:

```
class Unboxable a (rep :: RuntimeRep) (unboxedTy :: TYPE rep) | a -> rep, a -> unboxedTy where
  unbox :: a -> unboxedTy
  rebox :: unboxedTy -> a
```

An instance like this is perfectly fine:

```
instance Unboxable Int 'IntRep Int# where
  unbox (I# w) = w
  rebox = I#
```

but if I try to support tuples of unboxable values like

```
instance (Unboxable a repa unboxedTyA, Unboxable b repb unboxedTyB)
       => Unboxable (a, b) ('TupleRep '[ repa, repb ]) (# unboxedTyA, unboxedTyB #) where
  unbox (a, b) = (# unbox a, unbox b #)
  rebox (# a# , b# #) = ( rebox a# , rebox b# )
```

I get an error beyond my understanding:

```
    A levity-polymorphic type is not allowed here:
      Type: unboxedTyA
      Kind: TYPE repa
    In the type of binder ‘a#’
   |
32 |   rebox (# a# , b# #) = ( rebox a# , rebox b# )
   |            ^^
```

Similar error appears for `unbox` if `rebox` is commented out. If that matters, I'm on ghc 8.8.2.

What exactly does this mean and is there a way to express the last instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a variable with an unknown `RuntimeRep`. This instance is simply not possible. E.g. the instance for `(Float, Float)` would have to store/load the 32-bit values, but the instance for `(Double, Double)` would deal with 64-bit values. But, such instances would have to be specializations of this one instance and thus share code, making this distinction impossible. To catch this, when a variable is introduced, the type of its type is matched against `TYPE rep`, and if `rep` is not exactly known (essentially, the "calling convention" with which the value needs to be passed around), the error you've seen is raised. The phrase "levity polymorphism" is a bit of a relic, "levity" referring to the difference between lifted types (defined by containing a bottom value and which are all boxed (e.g. `Int`, `[String]`)) versus unlifted types (which don't have a bottom value, of which some are boxed (`ByteArray#`) and some are unboxed (`Int#`)) If you really wanted to, you could use Template Haskell to generate these boxing and unboxing functions, but you cannot get all of them (because there are infinitely many and you cannot use polymorphism).

Comment: "and thus share code" ← this is something I don't understand.  Why do they have to? Why can't the compiler in theory generate a custom function each time it generates a dictionary for this instance? I thought a little bit about this and I couldn't easily think why it'd break.

Comment: Because that's just how Haskell works. Polymorphic functions are not "templates"; they are compiled only once and levity polymorphism is not special enough to warrant adding such a template system. If you really want this templated, you could definitely write a compiler plugin that generates these typeclass instances on demand, but doing so in general makes the language irregular would need a very strong argument for why it's necessary. Generally, you don't need polymorphic unboxed code.

Comment: I think I'm getting more confused. What polymorphic function do you mean, `rebox` or its callers? The latter isn't necessarily polymorphic, and the former is already polymorphic just by the class definition, isn't it? Its very signature has a `rep` variable.

Comment: @0xd34df00d In the general case, at run-time an unbounded number of dictionaries can be needed, making it impossible to pre-generate them all at compile-time. E.g. `f :: Show a => a -> Int -> String ; f x 0 = show x ; f x n = f (Just x) (n-1)` is an example of a function which can be realized with Haskell typeclasses, but not, say, by C++ templates or rust generics (which are "templated").

Comment: @0xd34df00d Its callers. E.g. `oops :: Unboxable b r u -> (r, r) -> (# u, u #); oops = rebox` should be allowed. The call to `rebox` uses `Unboxable (b, b) (TupleRep '[r, r]) (# u, u #)`, but this simplifies to just `Unboxable b r u` through the instance. These are just the regular rules of Haskell classes. But the implementation of the function seems very complicated or impossible. Solutions: treat `oops` as a template, or force *all* `Unboxable` instances to be listed in the type. Both break polymorphic recursion and could lead to code size issues, the latter is "leaky".

Comment: @HTNW why are regular ("base") instances allowed then?

Comment: Because they don’t bind any variables of unknown representation? I’m not sure what you’re asking. Note that even they act weirdly: `works :: Unboxable b r u => u -> b; works = rebox; no :: Unboxable b r u => u -> b; no x = rebox x `. Functions are always represented by pointers no matter what (`(->) :: forall i o. TYPE i -> TYPE o -> TYPE LiftedRep `), so `works ` (and the implementation detail `rebox (Unboxable_dict _ x) = x `) can pass around a function of unknown argument representation as an opaque object, and it’s OK as long as `works` doesn’t attempt to call it.